# Zend_Auth and database session SaveHandler

Tags: zend-framework, authentication, session, doctrine

I have created `Zend_Auth` adapter implementing `Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface` (similar to [Pádraic's adapter](http://github.com/padraic/ZFPlanet/blob/master/library/ZFExt/Auth/Adapter/Doctrine.php)) and created simple ACL plugin. Everything works fine with default session handler. So far, so good.

As a next step I have created custom Session SaveHandler to persist session data in the database. My implementation is very similar to [this one from parables-demo](http://github.com/mlurz71/parables/blob/master/Parables/Session/SaveHandler/Doctrine.php). Seems that everything is working fine. Session data are properly saved to the database, session objects are serialized, but *authentication does not work* when I enable this custom SaveHandler.

I have debugged the authentication and all works fine up till the next request, when the authentication data are lost.

I suspected, that is has something to do with the fact, that I use `$adapter->write($object)` instead `$adapter->write($string)`, but the same happens with strings.

I'm bootstrapping `Zend_Application_Resource_Session` in the first Bootstrap method, as early as possible.

Does Zend_Auth need any extra configuration to persist data in the database?
Why the authentity is being lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of the problems.

I used 'data' as a column name. Session SaveHandler from parables-demo was calling code similar to this:

```
$string = 'test'
$doctrineModel->data  =  $string;
echo gettype($doctrineModel->data); // displays 'Array', not string as some would expect
```

So the data I wanted to save were accidentally converted to arrays.